# How to figure out an array element with key in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I am making something in the following picture:

[image]

I wrote the following code:

```
{ persons.map((person) => <li key = {person.id}> 
  <Person name={person.name} number={person.number}/> 
  <Button text={'Delete'} handler={deleteHandler} /> 
</li>) }
```

**The problem I am facing is, How to make the button (deleteHandler) work and delete the contact associated with it?**

What I think should be done -> find out the key associated (key in < li>) with the button and delete it from the array. **But then How do I find the key of < li> associated with the button?**

Note - I am using React hooks for state changes (NOT the classes), so, please suggest the answer accordingly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{ persons.map((person) => <li key = {person.id}> 
  <Person name={person.name} number={person.number}/> 
  <Button text={'Delete'} handler={() => deleteHandler(person.id)} /> 
</li>) }
```

In your handler you can filter your array using `person.id`

Answer (score 1):

You can pass particular id or object to delete inside that function

```
{ persons.map((person) => <li key = {person.id}> 
  <Person name={person.name} number={person.number}/> 
  <Button text={'Delete'} handler={() => deleteHandler(person.id)} /> 
</li>) }
```

Assuming that you have

const [persons, setPerson] = React.useState([......]);

```
const deleteHandler = item =>{
 let filtered  = persons.filter(person=> person.id!==item.id);
 setPerson(filtered)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First Add Persons to state data  like

```
this.setState( {persons:persons});
```

Then you can use the below code for delete operation

```
deleteHandler = (person) => {
  this.setState( { persons :  this.state.persons.filter(function( obj ) {
    return obj.id !== person.id;
    })
  });
}


this.state.persons.map((person, index) => {

  return(
        <li key = {person.id}> 
        <Person name={person.name} number={person.number}/> 
        <Button text={'Delete'} handler={()=>{this.deleteHandler(person)}} /> 
        </li>
  )
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either pass the key and check the key to find the index to delete an item or
pass the index to deleteHandler() function directly from click handler

```
{ persons.map((person, i) => <li key = {person.id}> 
  <Person name={person.name} number={person.number}/> 
  <Button text={'Delete'} handler={deleteHandler(i)} /> 
</li>) }
```

the function should be

```
const deleteHandler = (index) => {
  persons.splice(index, 1);
}
```